# R: Daily data to monthly

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have a large xts object, with multiple variable. The index is daily in that manner, it corresponds to exact days, however there is only one observation for each variable in a month. Is there a way to drop the day from the index and only keep year-month?

To ilustrate my problem for instance I have var1 with an observation on 2011-06-28 and var2 with observation 2011-06-30. I would like to index both as 2011-06

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow: Maybe it would be good if you edited your question title to something other people will easily find when googling for it. E.g. "How to change daily data to monthly in an xts object in R?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alternatively you could "tell" R that you are using dates of a certain format with the  `as.Date()` function and then use `format()` to change it to the format you desire.
Like this:

```
dates=c("2011-06-28","2011-06-29","2011-06-30","2011-07-1") #test string with dates in original format

dates2 <- format(as.Date(dates,"%Y-%m-%d"), format="%Y-%m") #changing the "%Y-%m-%d" format to  the desired "%Y-%m"

print(dates2)
```

Edit: If you only want to change the index of a xts:
`indexFormat(xts_object) <- "%Y-%m"`

Cheers
Chris

Comment: thanks, however for me it only partly works. It really drops the days, but it makes to character as well. As I try to use as.Date() afterwards it returns NA values. I do not understand why?

Comment: it doesnt work because as.Date() doesnt accept "%Y-%m" as an acceptable Date format (e.g. it needs a day). If you still want to do smth with it you could either try as.factor() or use as.yearmon() from the zoo package (probably better). BTW if you only want to change your xts index, I have edited my original post on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do this:
Use gsub (replace a pattern with whatever you want) with regex (a sequence of characters that define a search pattern in e.g. a string).
The pattern is done with regex, which has lots of metacharacters that allow you to do more advanced things. The dot (.) is a wildcard and the $ anchors it at the back. So the pattern is basically any 3 characters before the end and replace them with nothing.

```
your_object<-c("2011-06-28","2011-06-30")
gsub(pattern = "...$", replace = "", x = your_object)
```

Here is a guide for using gsub with regex (http://uc-r.github.io/regex).